# Побитовое сравнение двух строк

Tags: javascript, node.js

Подскажите в чем проблема. Если строки одинаковые то "1", а если нет то undefined. А мне надо чтобы true или false.

```
function slowStringComparison(givenSignature, computedSignature, cb) {
if (!givenSignature || !computedSignature || givenSignature.length !== computedSignature.length) {
    return cb(false);
}
var n = computedSignature.length;
var signaturesMatch = true;

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     signaturesMatch &= (computedSignature.charAt(i) == givenSignature.charAt(i));
}
return cb(null, signaturesMatch);}
```

Comment: суть побитовых выражений в том, что они возвращают число. Если нужна булевское значение используй логическое `&&` вместо побитового

Comment: на счет _slowStringComparison_ - ты погорячился. в твоем цикле все то же самое происходит, единственное, только проверки нет на null. Ну и яваскрипт уже давно позволяет обращаться к символу строки по индексу `computedSignature[i]` вместо вызова `charAt`

Comment: Спасибо, сделал так  signaturesMatch = computedSignature[i] == givenSignature[i];

Comment: плохо - так каждый раз будет перезаписываться значение и в итоге будет только результат последнего сравнения. То есть если все кроме последнего символа разные - signaturesMatch после цикла все равно покажет true

Comment: А как по правильному сделать?)

Comment: проверить значение _signaturesMatch_ - если `false` - делать break циклу, так как дальше нет смысла проверять. Либо использовать логическое &&: `signaturesMatch = signaturesMatch && computedSignature[i] == givenSignature[i];`

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В node.js есть намного более простой способ сравнить две строки побитово. Для этого нужно использовать класс [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), и его метод [`Buffer.equals`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_equals_otherbuffer):

```
function slowStringComparison(givenSignature, computedSignature, cb) {
    var givenBuff = Buffer.from(givenSignature),
        computedBuff = Buffer.from(computedSignature);

    cb(givenBuff.equals(computedBuff));
}
```